# Toggle HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

What am I missing to make it toggle? It seems logical to switch on the 2nd account but it only switch once.

```
function ShowHide()
        {
           var right_e = document.getElementById('id1'); 
           var left_e = document.getElementById('id2'); 
           if (top.visible_id == 'right') {
               right_e.style.display = 'none'; 
               left_e.style.display = 'block'; 
               top.visible_id = 'left';
           } else {
               right_e.style.display = 'block'; 
               left_e.style.display = 'none'; 
               top.visible_id = 'right';
           }    
        }


<a onclick ="javascript:ShowHide()" href="javascript:;" >click here</a>
```

Comment: What is `top.visible_id` ? Where is `top` declared?

Comment: why don't just using jQuery? it'll more easier.

Comment: you can actually use jQuery 'toggle()' effect

Comment: @Charlie - [jQuery ftw](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif).

Comment: There's probably a jQuery plugin for this.

Comment: I feel good that there is someone coming to SO (with a low score, like Bryan), that is asking a native JS question and not a question about some library.  This is good to see.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function ShowHide()
{

   if (document.getElementById('id1').style.display == 'block') {
       document.getElementById('id1').style.display = 'none'; 
       document.getElementById('id2').style.display = 'block'; 
   } else {
       document.getElementById('id1').style.display = 'block'; 
       document.getElementById('id2').style.display = 'none'; 
   }       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what `top` is, but you don't need to use that in your example.  Just check which div is visible:

```
function ShowHide()
    {
       var right_e = document.getElementById('id1'); 
       var left_e = document.getElementById('id2'); 
       if (right_e.style.display === 'block') {
           right_e.style.display = 'none'; 
           left_e.style.display = 'block'; 
       } else {
           right_e.style.display = 'block'; 
           left_e.style.display = 'none'; 
       }    
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you create same condition for if and else:

```
top.visible_id = 'right';
```

Comment: i think the question is 'What am I missing to make it toggle?'.

Answer (score -1):

If all you want to do is switch off the visibility of each element and one of them is initally hidden while the other is initially shown, try using jQuery's [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

```
function ShowHide() {
  $('#id1,#id2').toggle();
}
```

Comment: @vol7ron - Thanks. I forgot those could be combined. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Not saying it had to replace it, just offering it as an alternative, I'd check [jsperf](jsperf.com) to see what was faster, if I wanted to go the jQuery route.  Additionally, since you've combined them into one line, he can really git rid of the `ShowHide` function

Comment: @vol7ron - This is true. I'm guessing I got voted down because I'm using jQuery. Anywho, I suppose you are suggesting using: `<a onclick ="javascript:$('#id1,#id2').toggle();" href="#" >click here</a>` instead?

Comment: Not sure who voted you down, but no, don't include JS in the HTML. The `$(...)` can be in a JS to applied onDomReady.  I'd suggest giving the  anchor an id/class and doing `$('#linkID').click(function(){ /*toggle code*/ });`